# How can I detect a screen scroll on xamarin for an iOS app

Tags: xamarin, scroll, xamarin.ios, uiscrollview, xamarin.forms.carouselview

Here is the function in .cs that I want to change, that actually work with a slider and I would like to change it for a screen scroll or a drag or something that could detect a slide on my screen, the purpose of this code is to move the circles along a radial axis, what should I change in my .cs and .xaml ?

[image: Here is an image of it]

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            double newValue = e.NewValue;

            double baseValue = 0;

            int pos = (int)Math.Round((baseValue - newValue) / -1);

            Bureau.TranslationX = tX[(pos+37)% 100]; Bureau.TranslationY = tY[(pos+37) % 100];
            Repos.TranslationX = tX[(pos+12) % 100]; Repos.TranslationY = tY[(pos+12) % 100];

            MyAbsoluteLayout.TranslationX = t2X[(pos+62) % 100]; MyAbsoluteLayout.TranslationY = t2Y[(pos+62) % 100];
            MyAbsoluteLayoutOP.TranslationX = t2X[(pos+87) % 100]; MyAbsoluteLayoutOP.TranslationY = t2Y[(pos+87) % 100];

        }
```

I tried CarouselView and ScrollView without success but that's my first project in Xamarin using .cs and .xaml so I'm not sure of how those composants work any help would be appreciated

Comment: May I know what is `Bureau` and `Repos`? Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then add it to your post?